# Why can not I log in with my LDAP credentials on Symfony3?

Tags: symfony-3.1, fr3dldapbundle

I've install FR3LdapBundle & FOSUserBundle with Symfony3 successfully as per my blog, and I'm able to authenticate against this test LDAP server; but now I'm trying to authenticate against our internal Active Directory Server. 
Here is the change in config (I have obsfucated the config information on purpose):

```
fr3d_ldap:
   driver:
      host: somehost
      username: administrateur
      password: somepass
      port: 389
      accountDomainName: somedom.local
      accountDomainNameShort: somedom
   user:
      usernameAttribute: administrateur
      baseDn: ou=utilisateurs,dc=somedom,dc=local       
      attributes:
         - { ldap_attr: administrateur,  user_method: setUsername }
         - { ldap_attr: mail,  user_method: setEmail }
      filter: (&(ObjectClass=person))
```

The above is the only change I made. In my DEV logs, when I log in I get these important messages:

```
[2017-05-09 15:56:54] ldap_driver.DEBUG:  ldap_search(ou=utilisateurs,dc=somedom,dc=local, (&(&(ObjectClass=person))  (sAMAccountName=somedom\5cadministrateur)), [array]) {"action":"ldap_search","base_dn":"ou=utilisateurs,dc=somedom,dc=local","filter":"(&(&(ObjectClass=person))(sAMAccountName=somedom\\5cadministrateur))","attributes":[]} []
[2017-05-09 15:56:54] security.INFO: User somedom\administrateur not found on LDAP {"action":"loadUserByUsername","username":"somedom\\administrateur","result":"not found"} []
```

So I wonder if I need a special config?

Comment: Jérôme, if my EDIT #2 solved the problem, can you please click the checkmark by my answer to indicate it is correct.

Comment: it's already done no ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login as:

administrateur

instead, in the log it shows you are trying to login as "somedom\administrateur", but you don't need to add the domain.

I think that's the problem. Can you try it and if it doesn't work, I'll get you to try something else.

---

EDIT #2

I also see you have this set in your config.yml code:

```
attributes:
         - { ldap_attr: administrateur,  user_method: setUsername }
```

But instead should be:

```
attributes:
         - { ldap_attr: samaccountname,  user_method: setUsername }
```

Then if you use the LDAP browser, verify that the user exists in the `baseDn` you specified, and look for the attribute `sAMAccountName` and this is the user string you should enter in the login name field.

Comment: When I do not specify the domain it gives me the same error. The identifiers are invalid.

Comment: I think you need to use a LDAP browser to find out if your `baseDn` is correct. Here is a link to a free version: http://www.ldapadministrator.com/download.htm Browse to the `baseDn` you specified and verify that user is there. Typically in Active Directory a `cn=Users` is used.

Comment: OK I'll try this now. Thank you !!

Comment: After installing the ldap browser and checked the containers I can say that they are valid. At least the right containers are: dc = somedom, dc = local. What I had already tried later.

Comment: Please see my EDIT #2 changes. You just need the correct `baseDn` and attributes. You can also search on google for more info on LDAP filters. You might have to modify your config slightly.

Comment: I did not see sorry.

Comment: Checkmark by my answer please! Glad you got it working.